# Music streaming in libgdx doesn't work (JAVA)

Tags: java, libgdx, audio-streaming, background-music

So I've been working on a libGDX project, and I have encountered a problem here:

```
 public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter implements Screen {
      (...)
 @Override
 public void create() {
 (...)
 //Starts playing Main theme Music
 MusicPlayer.determineMusic(mainTheme, splash);

 }

 public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();

        //was:
        //splash.splashRenderer(mainTheme, batch, splashSprite);

        //changed to:
        splash.splashRenderer(batch, splashSprite);

    batch.end();

    System.out.println("******************End of Render******************");
}


public class SplashScreen {


 Music gameTheme ;

    public SplashScreen(){
    }

    public void splashRenderer(SpriteBatch batch, Sprite splashSprite) {
    batch.draw(splashSprite, 0, 0, MyConstants.WINDOW_WIDTH,                    MyConstants.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    }

   @Override
   public void show() {
       //gameTheme = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("blah.mp3"));
       //gameTheme.play();
   }

   @Override
   public void hide() {
       //gameTheme.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      //gameTheme.dispose();

   }

}

public class MusicPlayer {

   protected MusicPlayer(){
   }

   public static void determineMusic(Music Theme, AbstractScreen screen){

       if ((screen instanceof GameScreen) == false){
           Theme.play();
       }
   }

}
```

The code so far basically just loads a music file and a sprite and draws it on the screen through the splashRenderer method, but my problem is that the music doesn't start. 
Any help will be greately appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT1~ I implemented Screen, changed the method to splashRenderer(SpriteBatch, Sprite) & made the music file load and play in the show method and dispose() it in the hide and in the dispose methods. I didn't add anything to the pause() method because I think it is done automatically.

EDIT2~ I noticed that the music doesn't start this time either. The solution I came up with is to make a new class MusicPlayer() that will determine whether or not to play and which track. The musicPlayer is first called explicitly in the create() and will be recalled in when needed probably when handling mouseEvents.

Please provide feedback on these changes (good/bad/to be avoided for this and that reason etc). Thanks!

Comment: `SplashScreen` doesn't seem to implement `Screen`, which is odd. Also, you're calling `play()` about 60 times per second as you are calling it in the `render()` function instead of somewhere like `show()` in a `Screen`, which would explain why it doesn't "start".

Comment: Please see EDIT1 & 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

```
public abstract class BaseScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor
{
     public BaseScreen() 
     {
         windowWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
         windowHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
         AudioManager.getScreenThemes().put(this, getScreenMusic());
     }

     public void pause()
     {
         AudioManager.pause();
     }

     public void resume()
     {
         AudioManager.play();
     }

     public void show()
     {
         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
         AudioManager.switchMusic(this);
     }


     public abstract Music getScreenMusic();
     ...
}
```

Another Screen:

```
@Override
public Music getScreenMusic()
{
    return Resources.soundGameTheme;
}
```

AudioManager:

```
static
{
    screenThemes = new HashMap<Screen, Music>();
    currentlyPlayed = null;
}

public static boolean getSoundEnabled()
{
    return MyGame.getPreferences().getBoolean(Resources.soundEnabledKey);
}

private static Map<Screen, Music> screenThemes;

public static Music currentlyPlayed;

public static void play()
{
    if(getSoundEnabled() != false)
    {
        if(currentlyPlayed != null)
        {
            if(currentlyPlayed.isPlaying() == false)
            {
                currentlyPlayed.play();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void initialize()
{
    Resources.soundMainMenuTheme = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/main_menu.mp3"));
    Resources.soundGameTheme = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/game.mp3")); 
    Resources.soundMainMenuTheme.setLooping(true);
    Resources.soundGameTheme.setLooping(true);
}

public static void stop()
{
    if(currentlyPlayed != null)
    {
        if(currentlyPlayed.isPlaying() == true)
        {
            currentlyPlayed.stop();
        }
    }
}

public static void pause()
{
    if(getSoundEnabled() != false)
    {
        if(currentlyPlayed != null)
        {
            if(currentlyPlayed.isPlaying() == true)
            {
                currentlyPlayed.pause();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void switchMusic(Screen screen)
{
    if(screenThemes.get(screen) != currentlyPlayed)
    {
        if(screenThemes.get(screen) != null)
        {
            stop();
            currentlyPlayed = screenThemes.get(screen);
            play();
        }
    }
}

public static void dispose()
{
    Resources.soundMainMenuTheme.dispose();
    Resources.soundGameTheme.dispose();
    screenThemes = null;
}

public static Map<Screen, Music> getScreenThemes()
{
    return screenThemes;
}
```

Not the prettiest thing, I admit - I should have used a singleton of some sort like an enum, rather than make it static in this fashion. But it worked, although it basically plays a specific song when you navigate to a specific `Screen` and changes the song if the song to be played on the screen is different.

EDIT:

Preferences:

```
public class MyGame extends Game
{
    private static Preferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        ... 
        preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(Resources.preferencesName);
        ...
    }

    public static Preferences getPreferences()
    {
        return preferences;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yeah I don't really need such a complicated application since it will only change the track when going from the main menu to gamescreen and vise versa, instead I think I've made a simplified version what do you think?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, also I noticed that I managed to forget the most important method call from my copy paste, which is the `show()` function in `BaseScreen`.

Comment: Oh I really like the statement if(getSoundEnabled() != false) though :P

Comment: Well, I hate games on Android that don't allow the ability to turn off the sounds, so I need to mute my entire phone just to make sure it doesn't play its silly music. I've even had a game on my phone that played music even when I had the phone muted, that pissed me off. It's something that should be part of every game. :p